# Spring Security 3.2 inject AuthenticationManager (ProviderManager)

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

I am using the java configuration capabilities of Spring Security 3.2 and I was wondering if there is a way to inject the default AuthenticationManager instance into a custom (authentication) filter.
All attempts that I did so far ended in

No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]

Here my current bean definition:

```
@Bean(name="tokenAuthenticationFilter")
public Filter getTokenAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        TokenAuthenticationFilter filter = new TokenAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager);

        return filter;
}
```

I read that the following would implicitly tell spring security to use the default authentication manager.

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        ...
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

That I wanted to translate into the following java configuration snippet:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private TokenAuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider = null;


    @Override
    protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how your `AuthenticationManager` is declared?

Comment: Just added it to the question. I am probably doing something fundamentally wrong :-) Let's see.